# MySql display int as value

Tags: php, mysql

i'd like to store into a mailbox table the folder, the message should be inside as an int. Like 0 is inbox, 1 is outbox, ...

Is there a way to make the result of the query give me back a result like 'INBOX' for the stored value of 0?

Greetings

Comment: Please provide your table structure with data and expected result  and what you have tried so far

Comment: I would do it from the application side, like 

if($mailbox['Mail']['box'] = 1){ $mailboxvar = inbox } - this isn't quite what you asked for, but it might achieve the same effect

Answer (score 1):

You may store them as `ENUM('INBOX', 'OUTBOX')`. They will be stored as integers.

It'll be possible to write them as strings and as integer representation. They will be read as text by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case message when 1 then 'INBOX' when 2 then 'OUTBOX' END from your table
```

Is this what you are looking for?
[Refer this for more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested IF statement:

```
select if(folder=0, 'Outbox', if(folder=1, 'Inbox', 'Sent')) as folder, msg_id,... from messages;
```